# using c# how can i store string value in textbox.text

Tags: c#-3.0

i am waiting help me as soon as possible i have text box and two radio box if one radio box i selected and click button that the value of that radio box should display in text box how can i do this i am try by this code but i could not get still

correct this

```
string gender;
if (radio_male.Checked)
{
    gender = "Male";  
}
if (radio_female.Checked)
{
    gender = "Female";
}
textbox.Text = gender;
```

Comment: What's not working? What errors or exceptions are you getting?

Comment: where r u placing this code?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, saying "correct this", isn't the thing stack overflow is for, and it isn't really inviting us to answer your question either.

Also, next time, please give a bit more information (what have you tried? what is the error that is generated? what doesn't work properly), that way it is easier to answer,

But anyway, the answer.
I'm guessing that you're getting the error "use of uninitialized variable", since you do not necessarily initialize `gender`, which is required in C#.

Replacing `string gender;` with `string gender = "";` should do the trick.